# using dojox.mobile and dijit together

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

We are trying to make an app maker with dijit. Do you know what to do more or less to have the dojox.mobile.* branch running parallel to my dijit app ?

I know there is a seperate dojox.mobile.parser,... I guess, I need to fork it quite deep ?

I thought first about an iFrame but we need drag'n drop from the designer and the simulator.

Any help is welcome,
g

Comment: what do you mean by dojox.mobile.* branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dojox.mobile offers a very light-weight parser which can be used in place of the standard dojo.parser.  I think it skips stuff like attachpoints and probably wouldn't work too well with Dijit, so if you use both types of widgets on your page, stick with dojo.parser.  The parsers share some globals and are unable to co-exist, so do NOT load both.

Comment: Yup, thats how I ended up. My app designer and the simulator runs now well together. Thanks.